# Cannot cache from decorator (draper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, haml, draper

Caching is by far the most logic-intensive part of my view code, so I would like to do fragment caching from inside a decorator, however, I cant do it.

When i do this from my decorator:

```
def cached_name
  h.cache do
   "a name here"
  end
end
```

I get this:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have
>   expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating
>   nil.length

I instantiate my decorator from inside a controller

```
@presenter = SomePresenter::new
```

I am using HAML for my views

How can I succesfully cache from inside my decorator, so my view can do stuff like this

```
= @decorator.cached_logic_heavy_stuff
```

*UPDATE:* I have created a git repo showing my issue: https://github.com/houen/presenter_caching

UPDATE: This maybe works - see the repo

```
  include Haml::Helpers
  def another_way_to_try
    self.init_haml_helpers
    buffer = haml_buffer.buffer

    h.with_output_buffer(buffer) do
      h.cache do
        h.concat "i should still not be empty"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: what do you cache here? I don't see any block as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails' `cache` method tries to infer a cache key based on the view that it's being called from. Since you're not actually calling it from a view (but from inside an instance of a decorator class), I expect that it's bombing when trying to build a cache key.

You might try passing a cache key explicitly, via `h.cache "your cache key" do`. With a full stack trace, you can figure out where it's throwing the exception, and then work around that, as well. Without the full stack trace, it's harder to help you, though.

Edit: Looking at [Rails' caching code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb#L124), I think this might be a deeper issue; it's attempting to get the length of `output_buffer`, which isn't going to be available outside of your views' contexts (that is, within Draper). You might try adding:

```
def output_buffer
  h.output_buffer
end
```

But without testing it, I'm thinking it might not work exactly as planned without some more work. This is just a rough guess - I'd be surprised if this is actually the issue, but hopefully it gets you on the right path.

The note in the source there:

```
# VIEW TODO: Make #capture usable outside of ERB
# This dance is needed because Builder can't use capture
```

indicates that this isn't a fully-solved problem, so you may need to do a little digging around in the Rails internals to make this one work.

Comment: Yes, I came to that conclusion too, and you can actually use h.with_output_buffer do, but then there is the problem that HAML uses a different output buffer than ERB, so it needs to use that output buffer, too. It's a tall order, I know :)

Comment: Hmm - I think maybe I got it now :D see my edit. Chris, if you can verify that this works and won't cause problems, I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: Hah - it works. Actually you both helped with the answer. Wish I could give you both the bounty...

Comment: Nice. It's probably pretty easy to wrap that up in a little wrapper that exposes `cache` directly to decorators; that might be a good candidate for an upstream patch to Draper itself.

Comment: That's a really good idea Chris - if we can get that wrapped up with some Ruby inspection that checks if model.responds_to?(:cache_key) then one could cache almost *everything* within a (correctly used) decorator. That could help achieving this goal http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui ... I'll see if it makes good sense and if so try to get some of the others from Copenhagen Ruby Brigade (copenhagenrb.dk) involved in pursuing this. It could be an option on decorators to say :cache_aggressively => true

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `Rails.cache` directly might solve your problem; we do the same thing in our decorators with Rails 4.

```
def cached_name
  Rails.cache.fetch(source) do
    source.name # etc.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Draper, I believe you don't need to explicitly pass the view context. You will likely want to pass a model or collection to your draper present when you instantiate. Examples:

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :user

  # additional methods
end

# in the controller
@presenter = UserDecorator.new(@user)       # for an instance
@presenter = UserDecorator.decorate(@users) # for a collection
```

I suspect the nil object error you're getting is coming from another method call that's not listed in your code.

As for fragment caching from your decorator, you'll want to use the `concat` helper method to get this to work inside the decorator:

```
# your decorator class
def cached_name
  h.cache("some_cache_key") do
    h.concat "a name here"
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to pass it from the controller. The error is definitely due to the caching. You answer doesn't work, sadly:

Comment: def test
      h.cache do
        h.concat "hej"
      end
    end

Comment: same error: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? Also, the README for draper has some good examples of how to instantiate without passing a view_context: https://github.com/jcasimir/draper

Comment: Better - I'll link to a public git repo showing the error and problem in 5 minutes :)

Comment: It doesn't solve the error, though. See this repo: https://github.com/houen/presenter_caching

Comment: Whoops - edited your answer instead of my question. Sorry about that

Comment: you helped with the answer too, but unfortunately Stack Overflow doesnt let me split the bounty or award another bounty for the same question - sorry about that :( and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  include Haml::Helpers
  def another_way_to_try
    self.init_haml_helpers
    buffer = haml_buffer.buffer
    h.with_output_buffer(buffer) do
      h.cache "some_key10", :expires_in => 10.seconds do
        h.concat "i should still not be empty 2"
      end
    end
  end
```